# Why "offset+length<0" in jdk to make sure if the arguments if illegal?

Tags: data-structures, java

In jdk,there are many places to check the arguments abut array.eg.

```
/*..........
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *         If <tt>offset</tt> is negative or greater than
 *         <tt>buf.length</tt>, or if <tt>length</tt> is negative, or if
 *         the sum of these two values is negative.
 *
 * @param buf   Input buffer (not copied)
 * @param offset    Offset of the first char to read
 * @param length    Number of chars to read
 */
public CharArrayReader(char buf[], int offset, int length) {
    if ((offset < 0) || (offset > buf.length) || (length < 0) ||
            //$ offset+length
        (**(offset + length) < 0)**) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.buf = buf;
    this.pos = offset;
    this.count = Math.min(offset + length, buf.length);
    this.markedPos = offset;
}
```

why " (offset + length) <0 "is necessary?

Answer (score 2):

In Java `int` is signed so it can happen that two positive `int`s when added together result in a negative value. It's called wrap-around or [Integer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is checking for overflow.

Range of int is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

From the code you can see, there are places we need offset + length.  If offset + length is larger than 2,147,483,647 it is going to give problem, and (offset + length) < 0) is checking for such case.